# In MongoDB, $setIsSubset does not make efficient use of index

Tags: mongodb

```
Data:
student        class
s1          ["english"]
s2          ["maths", "geography"]
...
sN          ["history", "english"]
```

The field "class" is indexed, and values of it are all in array.

```
Query1:
db.students.explain('executionStats').aggregate([
  { $match: { $expr: { $setIsSubset:  [ "$class", [ "maths" ] ] } } }
])
```

,

```
Query2:
db.students.explain('executionStats').aggregate([
  { $match: { "$class": "maths" } }
])
```

The first one does a COLLSCAN or IXSCAN with indexBounds `class : [MinKey, MaxKey]`, depending on some conditions (e.g. the number of documents in the collection), while the second does a IXSCAN with indexBounds `class : ["maths", "maths"]`.

Given that the array of the "class" field can have multiple values, I need the $setIsSubset semantics here. I found [this](http://www.askasya.com/post/matchallarrayelements/). However, the double negation does a COLLSCAN instead of using the index as well. The corresponding query is as follows:

```
Query3:
db.students.explain('executionStats').aggregate([
  { $match: { class: { $not: { $elemMatch: { $nin: ["maths" ] } } } } }
])
```

It seems like MongoDB only does simple matching during the IXSCAN. Otherwise, it should be able to avoid doing a IXSCAN with [MIN, MAX] which essentially fetches all keys in the index. It can be possibly even slower than the COLLSCAN.

Wondering if there is anyway to achieve the $setIsSubset functionality, which can utilize the index efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An index is basically a mapping from a field value to a document.  In MongoDB each element of the array is listed in the index separately.

Using that example data, the index might look something like:

```
"geography" => s2
"english" => s1
"english" => sN
"history" => sN
"maths" => s2
```

This lends itself well to equality and inclusion searches.  In a query for`{ $match: { "$class": "maths" } }`, it would simply start at the first occurrence of  "maths", scan through the index entries until it reach a value that is not "maths", and pass the list of matching on to the next part of the query.  The same works for an `$in` search with a separate scanned range for each value being tested.

This can also work for `$nin` by scanning the ranges of the index that fall between each value in the query.

The query for `{$setIsSubset: {"$class", [input]}}` is essentially

```
${and:[
   {class:{$in:[input]}}, 
   {class:{$not:{$nin:[input]}}}
]}
```

In order to efficiently use an index with the curren structure, the MongoDB would need to scan all of the matching ranges to find documents that match, and scan all non-matching ranges for documents that do not match, sort one or both lists, and then compare the two lists to eliminate documents that have both matching and non-matching values.

I am not sure if that would perform better or worse than just scanning all of the documents.

It may be worth submitting a feature request to see if that can be implemented.

Also node that the following from the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#behavior) documentation:

> $expr does not support multikey indexes.

In MongoDB "multikey" means at least one of the fields in one of the indexed documents contains an array.

As a workaround, you might try doing separating that test into multiple aggregation stages, first test the array with `$in` which will use and index to reduce the number of documents examined, then test the with `$setIsSubset` will be able examine only the documents that have at least one matching value.

I would be very curious how this query performs compared with the two you have tried already:

```
db.students.explain('executionStats').aggregate([
  { $match: { class: { $in: [ "maths" ] }} },
  { $match: { $expr: { $setIsSubset:  [ "$class", [ "maths" ] ] } } }
])
```

Comment: You are right. `$expr does not support multikey indexes` is the root cause of this. 
However, theoretically, if each value of the list can be indexed separately, doing a set intersection of all the resulting document of each value should be faster than doing the scan. 
I've given up using MongoDB anyway, because of a bunch of non-optimal index usage by design.

Comment: To reply to your last example, unfortunately I haven't tried that. To my understanding, it can be faster in some scenarios depending on the the number of documents matching the filter. 
However, the fact that $expr cannot work with multikey index somehow negates my goal of making most queries covered to reduce disk IO (which is needed in my project).